# How to query an array of Mongo Ids in a single query?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am trying to build an array of Mongo ids and then return them from the database. These seem to be correct but return no results.

```
$itmes = array('541babe70f8da9c6388b4567','541babe70f8da9c6388b4568');
foreach($items as $id){
    $_ids[] = new MongoId($id);
}
var_dump($_ids); // looks good so far

// GET ItemID(s) FROM _id(s) PASSED
$cursor = $mongo->somecollection->find(
  array('_id'=>array('$in'=>$_ids) )
);
foreach ($cursor as $_id => $row) {
  var_dump($_id);
  var_dump($row);
}
```

I get no results. Is this not possible? How do I return multiple docs by Mongo ID in one query?

Comment: That looks fine. Are you sure your documents actually have a ObjectId in their `_id` field? The results from the cursor are key/value when used with "as" so the `$_id` is just a string when returned inside the loop.

Comment: When I look in mongo directly all my docs have a normal _id field... {    "_id" : ObjectId("541ca67d0f8da9e516fcb035"), ...

Comment: Then the query form is correct. But the question is "Do those id values you are passing in actually match anything"? That would seem to be a likely cause of a problem here. Ruling out the query syntax of course, which we have.

Comment: I messed around with it and got it to work. Only change I think I made though was... 
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
  var_dump($doc);
  
} ... unless i missed something else I changed. I reduced it to a single doc until i got that to work then did the $in for multiple.